# How to resize image by imagine extension in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I use the bellow function to resize images after upload to show on my post.
but it works just for images larger than 500px 300px. when I upload image smaller than this size, my website images row breaks down.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;    
public function upload() {
            $this->pictureFile->saveAs('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pictureFile->extension);

            Image::thumbnail('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile, 500, 300)
                    ->save('../files/upload/thumbnail-500x300/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pictureFile->extension, 
                            ['quality' => 70]);
            unlink('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.'  . $this->pictureFile->extension);
        }
```

Comment: Try giving mode property for thumbnail .  `Image::thumbnail('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile, 500, 300,\Imagine\Image\ManipulatorInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)`

Comment: this code doesn't work for images smaller than 500px 300px,

Comment: how can I resize small images to 500px 300px ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use resize method as below

```
 use yii\imagine\Image;  
 use Imagine\Image\Box;  

 public function upload() {
        $this->pictureFile->saveAs('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pictureFile->extension);

        Image::thumbnail('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile, 500, 300)
                ->resize(new Box(500,300))
                ->save('../files/upload/thumbnail-500x300/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pictureFile->extension, 
                        ['quality' => 70]);
        unlink('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.'  . $this->pictureFile->extension);
    }
```

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Image::thumbnail`, try the following

```
$imagine = Image::getImagine();
$image = $imagine->open('../files/upload/' . $this->pictureFile);
$image->resize(new Box(500, 300))->save('../files/upload/thumbnail-500x300/' . $this->pictureFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pictureFile->extension, ['quality' => 70]);
```

Haven't tested it but since yii's `Image` is just a wrapper over `Imagine` library, this should work with minor changes (if at all needed).

And yes, you need to `use Imagine\Image\Box;` in your file before using the code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Yii::setAlias('newsfolder', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web/extraimages/');

    $model->img = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'img');
    if (!empty($model->img)){
        $model->img->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@newsfolder/').$filename.'.'.$model->img->extension );
        $model->img =  $filename.'.'.$model->img->extension;
        $imagine = Image::getImagine();
        $image = $imagine->open(Yii::getAlias('@newsfolder/'.$model->img));
        $image->resize(new Box(500, 300))->save(Yii::getAlias('@newsfolder/'.$model->img, ['quality' => 70]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$imagine = Image::getImagine();
        $imagine = $imagine->open($openPath);
        $sizes = getimagesize ( $openPath ); 
        /*                   
           [0] => 604
           [1] => 244
           [2] => 3
           [3] => width="604" height="244"
           [bits] => 8
           [mime] => image/png
        ) */
        $width = 200;
        $height = round($sizes[1]*$width/$sizes[0]);        
        $imagine = $imagine->resize(new Box($width, $height))->save($savePath, ['quality' => 60]);
```